# In DataMapper, when using STI, what causes the error: undefined method 'key' for Object:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, single-table-inheritance, ruby-datamapper

I'm getting a very strange error with DM 1.2 and a model that is sub-classed using single-table inheritance (STI):

```
undefined method `key' for Object:Class
```

That happens when I do a `first` query on the base model "User" (`User.first`) - however, queries on sub-classes of that class work fine (SuperAdmin.first, etc.)

The error occurs in dm-core: `lib/dm-core/model.rb:588`

I've tried several things including importing an old database, switching to an old branch of the code, etc.  Nothing fixed it but one variation I got was:

```
undefined method `key' for NilClass:Class
```

Comment: Note To Self: When I get the `NilClass:Class` version, the app actually works!  But IT's still odd that that throws an exception.

Comment: Can you please post the code for your models?